# Does a Markov Decision Process have to be random?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

In reinforcement learning, a Markov Decision Process (MDP) is used to formalize the problem. On Wikipedia, you can read that an MDP is a "discrete-time **stochastic** control process." I take stochastic to mean that the transition dynamics are probabilistic, i.e. for a given state, action pair $s_t, a_t$, the next state $s_{t+1}$ is "chosen" according to some probability distribution,
$$p(s_{t+1} | s_t, a_t).$$
But what happens if we have a reinforcement learning problem with deterministic transition dynamics, like chess? Can they not be modeled with an MDP if MDPs have to be stochastic by definition?

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusion in your question because, as I understand it, there are two different questions:

1. Can all action outcomes in an MDP be deterministic?
2. Can we model games like chess using an MDP?

For question 1, the answer is yes. Consider an MDP where, for each action applied, the resulting state is chosen with probability 1. Picking something with a probability of one is a valid distribution, and therefore, one can model deterministic processes as an MDP. This is not very efficient, but it can be done.

The answer to question 2 is a bit more intricate because games like chess cannot be straightforwardly modeled as a deterministic process. This is due to the fact that in such cases, we need to model the choices of the opponent as a deterministic (or stochastic) process. In classic literature, these games are typically modeled as min-max (or and-or) trees, and algorithms like alpha-beta pruning (enhanced with various heuristics) are used to find a solution. This is what programs like (chess engines) [Stockfish do](https://blogs.cornell.edu/info2040/2022/09/30/game-theory-how-stockfish-mastered-chess/#:%7E:text=Stockfish%20uses%20a%20calculation%20method,a%20response%20to%20each%20strategy.).

On the other hand, programs like [AlphaGo](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature16961) model the opponent's choices as a stochastic selection based on heuristic estimates of these actions, where the states of the board are evaluated using a neural network (NN). Thus, in principle, one can model chess as an MDP given a good heuristic function for evaluating the states of the board. Note, howere, that this won't be an excat model of the opponet, since the opponent may chose to act not accroding to distribution computed by the NN.